# gcc detecting "subindex out of bound" error

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Surprisingly I found `gcc` can find this error when it compiles `C`. I simplified the code which still triggers the warning. I post the question for making clear the details of the techniques it uses. Below is my code of file `a.c`

```
int main(){
  int a[1]={0};
  return(a[1]);
}
```

My gcc version is `gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3`. When using `gcc a.c -Wall`, there is no warning; when using `gcc -O1 a.c -Wall`, there is a warning:

```
warning: ‘a[1]’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

and when using `gcc -O2 a.c -Wall` (or `-O3`), there is another warning:

```
warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]
```

The most surprising thing is that, when I give `a[1]` a value, then none of the above compiling options gives any warning. There is no warning even when I change the index to a huge number (of course the compiled file offends the operating system and will be kicked out),

```
int main(){
  int a[1]={0};
  a[2147483648]=0;
  return(a[2147483648]);
}
```

I think the above phenomenon is more of a function than a bug. I hope someone help me figure out what happens, and/or why the compiler is designed so. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Accessing memory past the end of the array results in [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

`gcc` is nice enough to go out of its way to detect, and warn you about, some of these errors. However, it is under no obligation to do so, and certainly cannot be expected to catch *all* such errors.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thank you. However, since `gcc` wants to do so, I wonder if there is any reason that in some scenarios it cannot catch all such errors. I know that a compiler does not run your code (this is especially the case for scientific computing), but where is the boundary?

Comment: @xinguo It's hard to tell exactly where it is. Some compilers are smarter, some are less smart, but one thing is sure: there are problems which are simply impossible to detect at compilation time.

Comment: I would believe that detecting such out-of-bound index in *all* cases could be proved equivalent to the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is not required to provide diagnostic for this kind of error, but gcc is often able to help; notice that these warnings often arise in part as a byproduct of the static analysis passes done for optimization purposes, which means that, as you noticed, such warnings often depend from the specified optimization level.